# How to change Cpanel Login page link?

Tags: .htaccess, cpanel

How can I change the link of my cpanel login page, like my login page opens when I type : www.mywebsitename.com/cpanel which I think is very insecure now as my visitors are growing. Top website don't follow such practice if you try /cpanel in their link, it redirects you to 404 Page. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should follow and read the posts from the cPanel official forum:

https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/disable-site-com-whm-and-site-com-cpanel.264932/#post1107121

I see no reason to provide a step by step explaination since it's already explained there.

Please give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

Changing/removing default cPanel URLs.

For the /whm and /cpanel urls, remove/change these lines or similar matched lines located on the /usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf file:

`ScriptAliasMatch ^/?cpanel/?$ /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/redirect.cgi`
 `ScriptAliasMatch ^/?webmail/?$ /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/wredirect.cgi`
 `ScriptAliasMatch ^/?whm/?$ /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/whmredirect.cgi`
Then run the following commands for the changes to take effect.

`/usr/local/cpanel/bin/apache_conf_distiller --update`
 `/scripts/rebuildhttpdconf`
 `/etc/init.d/httpd restart`